# Blazor Authorization and Authentication

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a new Blazor Server-Side Project. I want to implement authorization functionality with microsoft identity.
I can't find any good tutorial online.

- Creating and managing Roles
- Add/Delete/Update users and asign them to roles.
- Create Blazor Page to do this

Is anyone there who has done this before and could help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is very general. You can refer to https://www.section.io/engineering-education/authorization-and-authentication-in-server-side-blazor/ that explains the procedure step by step. You can also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0 for a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_S46MCokbk

Generally, it should be there out of the box, but you might have to create your own views for custom role/user management